# issue while starting genymotion

Tags: android, ubuntu, genymotion

I have followed these steps:

Change directory to where you downloaded the bin file and run following commands.

> - chmod +x genymotion-2.7.2-linux_x64.bin
> - ./genymotion-2.7.2-linux_x64.bin
> - to start genymotion
>   ./genymotion

Error generated while starting genymotion:

```
./genymotion: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /home/lokesh/Documents/genymotion/libQt5Core.so.5)
./genymotion: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /home/lokesh/Documents/genymotion/libQt5WebKit.so.5)
./genymotion: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /home/lokesh/Documents/genymotion/libicui18n.so.52)
./genymotion: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /home/lokesh/Documents/genymotion/libicuuc.so.52)
./genymotion: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /home/lokesh/Documents/genymotion/libQt5Qml.so.5)
```

Comment: Did you instal virtual box? uninstall the genny motion ande reinstall . don't forget to instal  virtual box.

Comment: yes I have installed virtualbox before installing genymotion

Comment: just uninstall everything. just install genny motion you will get the virtual box from it.

Comment: while installing it says "Installing for current user only. To install for all users, restart this installer as root."  is it a cause for issue ?

Comment: I have reinstalled virtualbox , genymotion but same issues are generated

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
sudo apt-get install libdouble-conversion1v5
```

Then run `./genymotion`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libdouble-conversion1v5`
was not working for me,
`E: Unable to locate package libdouble-conversion1v5`

I have Ubuntu 14.04, so I also used the alternative but after installing this same errors are generated:

`sudo apt-get install libdouble-conversion1`